# How do you complex join a number table with an actual table with many clauses dependent on the data from the number table?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table of numbers (PLSQL collection containing some_table_line_ids passed in from a website).

Then I have some_table also has columns -> config_data, config_state

I want to pull in all lines that have the same table_id from the all the table_ids in the number table.

I also want to pull in all lines that have the same config_data as each record pulled in from the first part.

So its a parent/child relationship.  This can be done in two for loops by selecting a line by an id in a cursor then another for loop selecting each line equaling the parents config data.  Each loop I am performing data manipulation on each line.

I would like to combine both these into a single cursor having all table ids that I need.
What would that look like?

Comment: Are you at all familiar with SQL and the join operation?

Comment: This isn't a clean join situation since the table_ids are just an array of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You just want to do a complicated join on different factors.  Something like:

```
select st2.*
from numbers n join
     some_table st
     on st.table_id = n.table_id join
     some_table st2
     on st2.config_data = st.config_data
```

Quite possibly, you actually want:

```
select distinct st.*
```

since you might otherwise have duplicates.  Or, you might want:

```
select n.table_id, st.config_data, st2.*
```

So you know which of the original values was responsible for bringing in the row.

Comment: the numbers table n doesn't have colunmns, its just an array, (PLSQL COLLECTION)

Answer (score 0):

You describe the array as a PL/SQL collection.  If you employ a SQL type instead you could include it in the FROM clause by using the TABLE function.

```
create type some_table_line_id_nt as table of number;
```

Something like:

```
select s.*
from some_table s
      join table(some_table_line_ids) t
          on s.id = t.column_value
```

(I haven't offered a complete solution as you haven't given enough details of table structure and data.)

Comment: I can't change that aspect of it.  I has to remain a collection.

Comment: @user1500053 - we can use SQL nested tables wherever we use PL/SQL collections.  So there's no functional change.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using start with and connect by prior.